# How can use cURL with Powershell to download from sharepoint using Microsoft Graph

Tags: powershell, curl

I am trying to download some files from my SharePoint or OneDrive using the Microsoft graph API. I want to only use cURL (The C:\windows\systems32\curl not invoke-request) and powershell.

I tried using the documentation from Microsoft here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service#4-get-an-access-token

and here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitem?view=graph-rest-1.0#instance-attributes

However the syntax seems to be off and I have been having some trouble.

Here is my starting code (This assumes you have setup an appid in the azure portal and obtained and client_id,client_secret, and tenant id):

```
curl -d 'client_id'='ENTERCLIENTIDHERE' \
-d 'scope'='https://graph.microsoft.com/.default' \
-d 'client_secret'='ENTERCLIENTSECRETHERE' \
-d 'grant_type'='client_credentials' \
 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/ENTERTANTANTHERE/oauth2/v2.0/token'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is code that will help you get a request from the Microsoft graph api using a token from your app id information, then it will generate a url for a specific file or folder of your choosing. You can also modify the code to just get yourself a token from the Microsoft graph API using only cURL and Powershell for windows.

```
#Generating the Token from the microsoft Graph API
$Result = C:\Windows\System32\curl -n -i -H "Host:login.microsoftonline.com" -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "client_id=ENTERCLIENTIDHERE&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default&client_secret=ENTERCLIENTSECRETHERE&grant_type=client_credentials" "https://login.microsoftonline.com/ENTERTENANTIDHERE/oauth2/v2.0/token" 
$x = $Result[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
$M = $x[16]
$k = $M -split ‘access_token":"’ 
$Resultk = $k[1] 
$ResulO = $Resultk.Substring(0,$Resultk.Length-2)

#Seeing the token in powershell to verify it came up properly
Write-Output $ResulO

#Requesting a download url from your own sharepoint or onedrive
C:\Windows\System32\curl -H "Host:graph.microsoft.com" -H "Authorization:Bearer $ResulO" -H "X-Cookie:token=$ResulO" "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/ENTERSITENAMEORSITEIDHERE/drive/root:/ENTERFILEPATHORFILEHERE?select=id,@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl"
```